# ActionScript/Flex - Stop recording on silence

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, microphone

Is there a way to start recording (writing sample data to a `ByteArray`) when there's activity (by activity I mean anything but silence), and stop recording when there's one second of silence?

Any guidelines on how to approach this would be extremely appreciated.

(Sorry if part or all of the above sounds stupid, this is my first-ever **ActionScript** application; I'm building it because I need microphone access in a Web app).

Comment: You can start by looking at the [activityLevel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#activityLevel) and [silenceLevel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#silenceLevel) properties of the [Microphone class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html) maybe also at the [activity event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#includeExamplesSummary)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I've tried using the `ActivityEvent` -- it never fired for me, even though my code closely matches that of the examples in Adobe's tutorials. I'm sure my microphone is operational; the sample event works, it's just the `ActivityEvent`. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `Microphone` there is 'silenceLevel' property and 'setSilenceLevel()' method. This method specified microphone signal level after which dispatching activity event.
[Microphone#setSilenceLevel() method reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#setSilenceLevel%28%29)

Comment: I see, well that should fix the recording start. Well what about **stopping** the recording after silence?

Comment: ActivityEvent.activating==true  => start record    ActivityEvent.activating==false => stop record

Comment: The `ActivityEvent` is never firing for me. Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: Try to check your sound settings in your operating system, but there is a problem duplicating on my computer. BUT! Microphones are a magic devices which switching between each other on my computer  =) In some conditions event are working correctly, in other is not firing. I'm confused. Do you check privacy settings in security panel with `Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);` method?

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539048/microphone-detection-actionscript-3?rq=1 . You can checking `activityLevel` by the timer, to take a decision about silence or not-silence in your microphone

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm going to do.